# How do you properly use AJAX to set the property of a class through a method

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around asynchronous calls at the class level. I understand why this doesn't work (single threaded JS calling method before the async call from the first method is complete) but I need some assistance on how to work around it/implement it correctly. I dumbed down my use case below.

Here would be my class:

```
class car {
    constructor(){
        this.carColor= null;
        this.getCarColorFromDB = this.getCarColorFromDB.bind(this);
    }
    getCarColorFromDB() {
        axios.get('carColor.JSON').then((color) => {
            this.carColor = color;
        })
    }
    outputCarColor() {
        return this.carColor;
    }
}
export default new car
```

and here would be a function that lives inside the component:

```
someFunction() {
    car.getCarColorFromDB();
    return <span>The cars color is {car.outputCarColor()}</span>
}
```

The behavior I'm after is for the car color to be set in the class via ajax and then be retrievable once I make my second call.

Comment: I have little knowledge of reactjs or ES6, but shouldn't you be using `this.carColor = null` ? Also, you're not closing your `.then(`

Comment: You're right, my mistake! I will fix that here soon!

Comment: your component is stateful so you need to use `this.setState`

Comment: You are correct, like I mentioned before, this is just a dumbed down use case